# How to update nested data in fire-base database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Nested data in firebase database snap pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwLfw.png) 
 Hi guys, I have store data in a real-time database which contains nested children and I had stored this data through using push feature in order to avoid overwriting issue but now the problem I do not know how to fetch particular data which I already highlighted in the snap image.  unfortunately, I am struggling in how I can fetch that nested data in order to perform editing or deleting functions. the following are the addUser class and the part of fetching the data into RecyclerView

```
public class AddUserAppointment {

   private String StartBusinse;
   private String StartBusinseTime ;
    private String EndBusinseTime ;
   private String startFirstAppoint ;
   private String endSecondAppointment ;
   private String AppointmentStuts;
  // private String AppointmentKey;  

    public AddUserAppointment() {
        ////empty
    }

    public AddUserAppointment(String startBusinse, String startBusinseTime, String endBusinseTime, String startFirstAppoint, String endSecondAppointment, String appointmentStuts) {
        StartBusinse = startBusinse;
        StartBusinseTime = startBusinseTime;
        EndBusinseTime = endBusinseTime;
        this.startFirstAppoint = startFirstAppoint;
        this.endSecondAppointment = endSecondAppointment;
        AppointmentStuts = appointmentStuts;
    }

    public String getStartBusinse() {
        return StartBusinse;
    }

    public void setStartBusinse(String startBusinse) {
        StartBusinse = startBusinse;
    }

    public String getStartBusinseTime() {
        return StartBusinseTime;
    }

    public void setStartBusinseTime(String startBusinseTime) {
        StartBusinseTime = startBusinseTime;
    }

    public String getEndBusinseTime() {
        return EndBusinseTime;
    }

    public void setEndBusinseTime(String endBusinseTime) {
        EndBusinseTime = endBusinseTime;
    }

    public String getStartFirstAppoint() {
        return startFirstAppoint;
    }

    public void setStartFirstAppoint(String startFirstAppoint) {
        this.startFirstAppoint = startFirstAppoint;
    }

    public String getEndSecondAppointment() {
        return endSecondAppointment;
    }

    public void setEndSecondAppointment(String endSecondAppointment) {
        this.endSecondAppointment = endSecondAppointment;
    }

    public String getAppointmentStuts() {
        return AppointmentStuts;
    }

    public void setAppointmentStuts(String appointmentStuts) {
        AppointmentStuts = appointmentStuts;
    }
```

**fetch data class**

```
public class ListAppointmentCustomerClass extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference AppointmentRef,SeconDref;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String PostKey;
    private RecyclerView ListAllApointment;
    private String pushkey;
    private Button Book,Cancel;
    private String AppointmentKey;
    private String keyId;
    private String m_Text = "";
    private boolean AppointmentCondation = true;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_appointment_customer_class);
        //pushkey = AppointmentRef.getKey();

        PostKey = getIntent().getExtras().get("Postkey").toString();

        AppointmentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Appointments").child(PostKey);

        ///

        ////
        ListAllApointment = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.ListAppointmentView);
        LinearLayoutManager customerLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        customerLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        customerLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        ListAllApointment.setLayoutManager(customerLayoutManager);
        //TODO:All the methods shoud be list here
        DisplayuploadedAppointment();
    }

    public static class HolderClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View mView;
        Button bookAppointment , CancelAppoinment;

        public HolderClass(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            bookAppointment = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.BookAnppointments);

        }

        public void setStartFirstAppoint(String startFirstAppoint){
          TextView StartAppointment = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.StartAppointmet);
          StartAppointment.setText(startFirstAppoint);
        }
        public void setEndSecondAppointment(String endSecondAppointment){
            TextView EndAppointment = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.EndAppointment);
            EndAppointment.setText(endSecondAppointment);

        }
        public void setAppointmentStuts(String appointmentStuts){
            TextView appointment = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.BookingStatus);
            appointment.setText(appointmentStuts);
        }



    }

    private void DisplayuploadedAppointment() {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AddUserAppointment,HolderClass >AppointmentRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AddUserAppointment, HolderClass>
                        (
                                AddUserAppointment.class,
                                R.layout.listallapointment,
                                HolderClass.class,
                                AppointmentRef
                        ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(HolderClass viewHolder, AddUserAppointment model, final int position)
                    {


                        viewHolder.setStartFirstAppoint(model.getStartFirstAppoint());
                        viewHolder.setEndSecondAppointment(model.getEndSecondAppointment());
                        viewHolder.setAppointmentStuts(model.getAppointmentStuts());
                        viewHolder.mView.setTag(position);
                        viewHolder.bookAppointment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Appointments").child(PostKey);

                                final String id = getRef(position).getKey();
                                mDatabase.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                            System.out.println("Id"+id);
                                            String bookingCondation = dataSnapshot.child("appointmentStuts").getValue().toString() ;
                                            HashMap hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                                            hashMap.put("appointmentStuts","Boooked");

                                           System.out.println("Postkey"+PostKey);
                                           mDatabase.updateChildren(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {

                                               }
                                           });



//                                            String key = snapshot.getKey().toString();
//                                            System.out.println(key);


//                                            String bookingCondation = dataSnapshot.child("appointmentStuts").getValue().toString() ;
//                                            System.out.println("Appointment Status "+bookingCondation);

                                           // Log.e("Appointment : " , "" + appointmentStuts+ap.getStartFirstAppoint()+key);


                                        }

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });


                    }
                };
        ListAllApointment.setAdapter(AppointmentRecyclerAdapter);



    }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the users to get their data like this:

```
  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Appointments").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            while (dataSnapshots.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshots.next();
                AddUserAppointment user = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(AddUserAppointment.class);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: For the Iterator it is fine but the ArrayList that you put, Which Appointments you refer to I mean the collection of the ArrayList refers to where. Thanks in advance

Comment: My bad! i was too weak yesterday. I wanted to retrieve the data to `arrayList` before, then i realized you have a model class already. I forgot to remove the `ArrayList` object.

Comment: You can try and let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: it doesn't, it still fetching all the data from parent-child which is 3dp8ich......etc

Comment: Just change your database ref to `.child("Appointments").orderBy("AppointmentStatus").equalTo("Available").addListernerForSingleValueEvent()....`

Comment: Hey, did you get it now?

Comment: Hi, it worked in a different way, I just passed the Appointment id and then check whether the appoinemntStatus.equalTo("Available") or not .However, Thank you so much you have opened a way for me to figure it out

Comment: Hey Alex, you can mark it as answer if it works for you. For others facing related problem. They will be able to see it as answer. Thanks