# Data not appear in the RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have developing an appointment system and I want to list the uploaded appointments in Recyvlerview so I have created a model class the use for storing the data as well as use it if the purpose. In addition, the data is existing and I already ensure from the AddVlueListiner so the following are the classes and layout

**List Appointment Class**

```
    public class List_appointment extends AppCompatActivity {
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private DatabaseReference mReference;
        private Button ChatButton;
        private TextView StartBusinseTime, EndBusinessTime, StartAppointment, EdnAppointment;
        private RecyclerView OwnerListAppointment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_appointment);
        //Todo:Firebase Instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String Uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Appointments").child(Uid);//make sure from this path
//        mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
//                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
//                        System.out.println("List owner appoinemt"+snapshot);
//                    }
//                }
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
//
//            }
//        });

        OwnerListAppointment = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.OwnerListAppointment);
        LinearLayoutManager OwnerLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        OwnerLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        OwnerLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        OwnerListAppointment.setLayoutManager(OwnerLayoutManager);


    }

    public static class OwnerListAppointmentClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {//class into class is called liner class
        View mView;

        public OwnerListAppointmentClass(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setStartFirstAppoint(String startFirstAppoint) {
            TextView StartAppointment = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.StartAppointmet_Owner);
            StartAppointment.setText(startFirstAppoint);
        }

        public void setEndSecondAppointment(String endSecondAppointment) {
            TextView EndAppointment = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.EndAppointment);
            EndAppointment.setText(endSecondAppointment);

        }

        public void setAppointmentStuts(String appointmentStuts) {
            TextView appointment = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.EndAppointment_Owner);
            appointment.setText(appointmentStuts);
        }

    }


        private void DisplayListOfAppointments() {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AddUserAppointment, List_appointment.OwnerListAppointmentClass> AppointmentRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AddUserAppointment, OwnerListAppointmentClass>
                        (
                                AddUserAppointment.class,
                                R.layout.listappointmentclass,
                                OwnerListAppointmentClass.class,
                                mReference


                        )
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(OwnerListAppointmentClass viewHolder, AddUserAppointment model, int position) {
                        final String SAppoinemtnKey = getRef(position).getKey();
                        viewHolder.setStartFirstAppoint(model.getStartFirstAppoint());
                        viewHolder.setEndSecondAppointment(model.getEndSecondAppointment());
                        viewHolder.setAppointmentStuts(model.getAppointmentStuts());

                    }
                };
        OwnerListAppointment.setAdapter(AppointmentRecyclerAdapter);


}
```

**Modle Class**

```
public class AddUserAppointment {

   private String StartBusinse;
   private String StartBusinseTime ;
    private String EndBusinseTime ;
   private String startFirstAppoint ;
   private String endSecondAppointment ;
   private String AppointmentStuts;
   private String Uid;
  private static ArrayList<AddUserAppointment>AppointmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ArrayList<AddUserAppointment> getAppointmentList() {
        return AppointmentList;
    }



    public AddUserAppointment() {
        ////empty
    }

    public AddUserAppointment(String startBusinse, String startBusinseTime, String endBusinseTime, String startFirstAppoint, String endSecondAppointment, String appointmentStuts, String uid) {
        StartBusinse = startBusinse;
        StartBusinseTime = startBusinseTime;
        EndBusinseTime = endBusinseTime;
        this.startFirstAppoint = startFirstAppoint;
        this.endSecondAppointment = endSecondAppointment;
        AppointmentStuts = appointmentStuts;
        Uid = uid;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return Uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        Uid = uid;
    }

    public String getStartBusinse() {
        return StartBusinse;
    }

    public void setStartBusinse(String startBusinse) {
        StartBusinse = startBusinse;
    }

    public String getStartBusinseTime() {
        return StartBusinseTime;
    }

    public void setStartBusinseTime(String startBusinseTime) {
        StartBusinseTime = startBusinseTime;
    }

    public String getEndBusinseTime() {
        return EndBusinseTime;
    }

    public void setEndBusinseTime(String endBusinseTime) {
        EndBusinseTime = endBusinseTime;
    }

    public String getStartFirstAppoint() {
        return startFirstAppoint;
    }

    public void setStartFirstAppoint(String startFirstAppoint) {
        this.startFirstAppoint = startFirstAppoint;
    }

    public String getEndSecondAppointment() {
        return endSecondAppointment;
    }

    public void setEndSecondAppointment(String endSecondAppointment) {
        this.endSecondAppointment = endSecondAppointment;
    }

    public String getAppointmentStuts() {
        return AppointmentStuts;
    }

    public void setAppointmentStuts(String appointmentStuts) {
        AppointmentStuts = appointmentStuts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as your last question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156206/how-to-update-nested-data-in-fire-base-database-android ?

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

First, the implementation of `RecyclerView` is not standard; guessing its the [Firebase UI RecyclerView](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md), try to implement it by creating your own class and then extenting the Firebase RecyclerView.

Secondly, you never called the method `DisplayListOfAppointments()`, so there is no ViewHolder object created, and also, it didn't got attached to `RecyclerView`, i.e. the last line of the same method:

```
OwnerListAppointment.setAdapter(AppointmentRecyclerAdapter)
```